# $p-x^2$ divides $p-y^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility

$p$ is a prime with $p>5$, and let $S = \{p − n^2 : n \in\mathbb Z, n^2 < p\}$. Prove that $S$ contains two elements $a, b$ such that $1 < a < b$ and $a$ divides $b$.

Let $a = p-x^2 $ and $ b = p-y^2$

Because $x$ and $y$ are both less than or equal to $\sqrt p$, I was reminded of Thue's lemma and I tried it, but it doesn't seem to work. I thought of using the Chinese Remainder Theorem, but if I use that, I have no idea how to make sure the solution is less than or equal to $\sqrt p$. I can't think of anything else, at least not thus far.

Comment: Where do x, y come in in the body of your post.  You define p, S, n, a, b.  No x, y.  What are x and y?  Please do not depend on the title to express part of your question.  The question body should be all inclusive.  Also how do a, b relate to your title or the rest of the information in the body of your question.  Did you mean x, y such that $1\lt x \lt y$ and $x\mid y$?

Comment: sorry, I changed variables partway through and didn't notice

Comment: Thanks for editing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If not a very sophisticated proof is needed only a simple one, then let $c \in\mathbb Z$, for which $c(p-x^2) = p-y^2$
and from this we can get
$(c - 1)(p-x^2) = (x + y)(x - y) \Rightarrow x > y$.
We can set either $p-x^2 = x + y \Rightarrow y = p - x^2 - x$,
or $p-x^2 = x - y \Rightarrow y = x - (p - x^2)$,
in both cases we can show that there exist $(x, y, c)$ so that all the initial conditions apply.

Comment: Looks like I was thinking too far and didn't notice that a simple solution worked. Nice!

Comment: @Confusedcat Thanks, you may consider accepting this as an answer if you don't want to leave the question open.